# How to remove a Key from a HashMap using the Value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an assignment that requires me to has a Map that is configured...

```
Map<Integer,Event> eventList = new HashMap<>();
```

And I have to write a method that has the following header...

```
public String removeEvent(Event eventObj)
```

The idea is to pass it an Event object, check if the event already exist as a value in the Map, and if it does, remove it and return a String message as confirmation that it has been removed.

The issue I have is that it stipulates that I cannot iterate over the map for the solution.

I can use the containsValue() method, or my overidden equals() method, to check if the object already exists in the map, but I now have the issue where I am not sure how I can remove the key pair value that matches?

Any assistance would be good as I am quite new to Maps and often struggle moving between Key and Value.

Comment: why return String ?

Comment: Pass. This is a stipulation of the assignment. Not would I would do however.

Comment: It may be, but I cannot iterate for the solution to this. And all other threads I could find involved iteration

Comment: why cannot iterate ? you cannot without

Comment: Again - Pass. I assume the University have their reasons for posing the question as such and stipulating that I cannot use iterators and that it must return a String. I am sure they have their reasons. But god only knows what they are as?? I am just stuck with having to come up with a solution that fits.

Comment: What is the Key? Can it be derived from associated value?

Comment: The key is an Integer and is Static so the Integer id increments each time an new Event is added to the map.

Comment: Store a reference to the value in Event when it is added as, say, id and you are good. `map.remove(event.getId());`

Comment: @PaulHarper Just to be clear, you can't use the keywords `for` or `while` in your code no matter what, right?

Comment: Well, the exact wording of the assignment says not to use 'iteration'. Personally I am taking that to mean a for each loop. I am probably still going to use an if or while loop. I cannot see how it can be done without iterating. I certainly cannot see that it is possible without at least an 'if' or 'while' loop.

Comment: @PaulHarper Post the exact wording of the assignment. Either you've abstracted away vital information, or the problem is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot iterate<sup>1</sup> the `Map`, you need another `Map` to represent the reverse mapping; e.g.

```
Map<Integer,Event> forwardMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<Event,Integer> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();

....

void remove (Event event) { 
    Integer key = reverseMap.get(event);
    if (key != null) {
        forwardMap.remove(key);
        reverseMap.remove(event);
    }
}
```

Obviously, all operations that modify the forward map must make the corresponding modification to the reverse map.

---

<sup>1 - I'm assuming that *all* forms of iteration are disallowed.  That includes using Java 8+ streams, where the iteration is happening under the hood.  If that is not what you mean, then update your Question to make it clear what is allowed and what it not allowed.</sup>

Comment: How do you populate the `reverseMap` without iterating?

Comment: You don't.  You populate it in parallel with the forward map.  See the last sentence of my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be:

```
eventList.values().remove(eventObj);
```

However this uses iteration under the hood. You cannot solve this without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot iterate, you should call a function that will do that for you internally. [`Map.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) should work. This method will go through each entry and replace its value with what is returned by the BiFunction parameter. The first parameter of the function is the key, second is the value. It should return the new value.

Example:

```
map.replaceAll((key, value) -> {
    if ("foo".equals(value)) return null;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Changing the key to map to null is not the same as removing the entry. `map.keySet().contains(key)` will still return true

Comment: `replaceAll` uses iteration.

Comment: Then I guess the solution would be to use a rudimentary bimap.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write two-phase code:

1. Collect the keys that belong to that value
2. Remove those keys - given that they have still the same value

One might consider some sort of locking in case of multi-threaded access. For the sake of simplicity we put the burden of this to the caller of the method:

```
public String removeEvent(Event eventObj) {
    // phase 1: collect the related keys
    List<Integer> keys = eventList.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> eventObj.equals(entry.getValue()))
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // phase 2: remove those keys
    for (Integer key : keys) {
        // this version of reomve double-checks if that key still has that value
        eventList.remove(key, eventObj);
    }

    // it would be good to know the criteria of failure - when should we return something else?
    return "Success";
}
```

Comment: You don't need the loop to remove the keys. You can write `eventList.keySet().removeAll(keys);`

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy yeah, that's more elegant. However, it doesn't check whether the values have changed or not. It all boils down to the requirements after all :)

Comment: `eventList.entrySet()` == iteration